# Need to get at the data sent to a web service thru the wsdl service reference (Windows c#)

Tags: c#, xml, soap, wsdl, service-reference

This is a difficult one so hoping someone has been here before with this.

Long story short - we have several hundred web services in projects that use Microsoft's "Add Service Reference" to generate methods from the wsdl.

We now need to push these thru another service first and relay on the call to the original server and do the same with the response.

We have a service that takes soap requests (XML) and does this already so want to reuse this if possible.

How do we get at the SOAP request data either via intercepting the web service call (redirect to stream or file etc.) or see what it would have generated as SOAP XML.

We have no way of using current software to redirect these calls so need a bespoke solution as we need also to track everything going thru the re-director.

The existing rerouting service takes a SOAP XML and passes to another URL and works well for a different project - so we just need the SOAP XML produced by the web service call and we can reuse the service.

//Example call to a simple wsdl generated interface...

Calc.CalculatorSoapClient clc = new Calc.CalculatorSoapClient(); 
clc.Open();

int x = clc.Add(1, 2); // need to get soap that would have been sent to the web service here
clc.Close();

Comment: Do you control all of the services or are they external? Why not just put all the WebMethods in to the relay service and stop using several hundred web services if you're just going to relay them all? Are they used elsewhere?

Comment: It's a very long story but goal posts have shifted over time and while the original system was hosted all within the same domain parts of it now are becoming external. We need to reroute thru a secure system (which we have created successfully for another project with code-built SOAP requests etc.).We are trying not to have to change huge amounts of code/test etc but instead find an easier method to reuse an existing solution.